# Are there any combination of new ES6+ operators to add concatenated fields in array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, operators, concatenation

Are there any combinations of the new ES6 operators (e.g.- spread, rest, etc..) that would allow me to add a new concatenated field for all objects in an array of objects?  For example, if I have the array:

```
myArray = [
    {a: 'A', b: 'B'},
    {a: 'C', b: 'D'},
    {a: 'E', b: 'F'}
];
```

I want to create a new array, that adds a concatenated field, ab:

```
myConcatArray = [
    {a: 'A', b: 'B', ab: 'AB'},
    {a: 'C', b: 'D', ab: 'CD'},
    {a: 'E', b: 'F', ab: 'EF'}
];
```

Obviously this can easily be done by iterating over the elements in the array, but is there a way to do so more concisely by using the new ES6+ operators?

Comment: Do you want to mutate the original objects?

Comment: Are those properties the real "names" or can they change?

Comment: @SLaks: no, the objects should be immutable, so I'd be constructing a new array.

Comment: @Andreas the property names will not change (every element will have an a and b, which is enforced using Typescript and an interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.map()` to make a new array by transforming an existing array:

```
myArray.map(obj => ({...obj, ab: obj.a + obj.b}))
```